# Matching redirected nginx requests from original path

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

My current configuration rewrites all php pages to `/index.php?$query_string`, I need this to work for a specific path, but when using a location block for this, once the path has been rewritten it no longer matches. Is there a way to to forward a request to fpm and rewrite the URI in same location block without redirecting? Or an alternative that will  accomplish what I want?

Here is my specific code:

```
location /civicrm/group {
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_send_timeout 0;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 0;
        include snippets/fastcgi-common.conf;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS 'on';
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
    try_files $uri @drupal;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-modify.conf;
    include snippets/fastcgi-common.conf;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS 'on';
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location @drupal {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

The problem is this means I lose information on the original base path and can no longer match the original location, for example:

1. Request `/civicrm/group?reset=1`
2. Match location `/some/path`, this is where I would like to change
   the settings for `php-fpm`.
3. I need to change the URI, so I rewrite to
   `/index.php?$query_string`
4. Now, I start matching from the beginning, but now the location
   `/some/path?reset=1` wont match (problem)
5. So I match the regular php location block.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no static files under this path, you could send all requests directly to `index.php` with:

```
location /civicrm/group {
    try_files /index.php =404;

    fastcgi_send_timeout 0;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 0;
    include snippets/fastcgi-common.conf;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS 'on';
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

Notice that the `/index.php` term has been moved so that it is no longer the last parameter and no longer contains the query string. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Why is the query string removed?

Comment: Does it need to be removed?

Comment: In this position, it is a file name. The original query string should be passed to PHP as normal.

Comment: So I don't need to do anything extra to have it passed to PHP?

Comment: Unfortunately I just get 404. Static files are not in that path but there are static files that need to be loaded when I visit that URL.